# Java Record custom constructor

Tags: java, record

I have a java record that takes in a list

```
public record Zoo(List<Animal> animals ) {

     public Zoo(Collection<Animal> animals) {
         this(new ArrayList<>(animals));
     }

     ...
}
```

However, the animals are not in sorted order, and I want to create record where animals are sorted. Is this possible in Java record?

In plain java class, I could have

```
public class Zoo {
   ...
   public Zoo(List<Animal> animals) {
     this.animals = animals.sort(someComparator);
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the same as with your "plain Java class".

```java
import java.util.Collections;

public record Zoo(List<Animal> animals) {

  /*
   * The canonical constructor copies the 'animals' list so that both
   * constructors have consistent behavior (i.e. they both result in
   * the list being copied). Plus, since you want to sort the list, it's
   * a good idea to create a copy anyway to avoid side-effects.
   *
   * FIXME: When the non-canonical constructor is used, the 'animals' list
   *        will be copied twice. If anyone can think of a way to avoid
   *        this, please let me know.
   */

  // explicit canonical constructor
  public Zoo(List<Animal> animals) {
    animals = new ArrayList<>(animals);
    animals.sort(/* comparator */);
    this.animals = Collections.unmodifiableList(animals);
  }

  // a non-canonical constructor; must delegate to canonical constructor
  public Zoo(Collection<Animal> animals) {
    this(new ArrayList<>(animals));
  }
}
```

The first constructor is an explicit declaration of the canonical constructor. From the documentation of [java.lang.Record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html):

> A record class has the following mandated members: a *canonical constructor*, which must provide at least as much access as the record class and whose descriptor is the same as the record descriptor; a private final field corresponding to each component, whose name and type are the same as that of the component; a public accessor method corresponding to each component, whose name and return type are the same as that of the component. If not explicitly declared in the body of the record, implicit implementations for these members are provided.
>
> [...]
>
> The primary reasons to provide an explicit declaration for the canonical constructor or accessor methods are to validate constructor arguments, perform defensive copies on mutable components, or normalize groups of components (such as reducing a rational number to lowest terms.)

Note all other constructors must eventually delegate to the canonical constructor.

Comment: If you want to pass an immutable `List<Animal>` to the constructor, you need to cast it to `Collection<Animal>`.

Comment: You can also sort a copy of the list and then set it to the field `animals`. Although the copy in `Zoo (Collection<Animal>)` becomes redundant.

Comment: I found this to be a good question to reveal the problem with `record`.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the issues with List vs. Collection, why not just define the Zoo as having a `Collection<Animal>` instead of a `List<Animal>`?

```
public record Zoo(Collection<Animal> animals) {
    public Zoo(Collection<Animal> animals) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(animals, "animals is null");
        List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>(animals);
        Collections.sort(list);
        this.animals = list;
    }
}
```

If there is client code that really needs `animals()` to return a `List` rather than a `Collection`, you could add a custom accessor:

```
    public List<Animal> asList() {
        return (List<Animal>) animals;
    }
```

This cast is safe since the canonical constructor will never assign any type to `animals` that is not an `ArrayList`. I stuck with `ArrayList` since that was in your original example, but records are immutable by default, so having a member that is mutable is somewhat questionable. If mutability is not needed, you can replace the last line of the constructor with

```
this.animals = List.copyOf(list);
```

Or even replace the last three lines of the constructor with

```
this.animals = animals.stream().sorted().toList();
```

Comment: The +1 is for making this Immutable, which should be the default for records anyways (too bad Java has no support to do this easily)

Answer (score 2):

The answer proposing to use `this(..)` has the limitation that `this()` must be the first statement.

To overcome that limitation, you can use the static contructor, like:

```
public record Zoo(List<Animal> animals) {

     public static Zoo fromAnimals(Collection<Animal> animals) {
         List<Animal> listAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>(animals);
         listAnimals.sort(Animal::compareTo);

         // ... any other pre-processing, possibly using additional parameters

         return new Zoo(listAnimals);
     }

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Stream API:

```
public record Zoo(List<Animal> animals ) {

     public Zoo(Collection<Animal> animals) {
         this(animals.stream().sorted(someComparator).collect(Collectors.toList()));
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: The implicit constructor `Zoo(List<Animal> animals)` is valid in your code. If you call it directly, the `animals` will not be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Remember until your constructor has finished to run, your input is not final, so you can overwrite your record class constructor as follows:

```
public record Zoo(List<animal> animals ) {
     public Zoo {
        Collections.sort(animals, your_comparator);
    }
}
```